# Android XML string 'et cetera' encode?

Tags: android, android-xml

This gives me an error:

```
<string name="txt_urbeautiful">What...</string>
Replace "..." with ellipsis character (…, &&;#8230;)
```

So how do I encode 'et cetera...' in XML?

Comment: The answer is given in the question itself. `Replace ... with ellipsis character(#8230)`;

Comment: Ellipsis is `&#8230;`

Comment: Thanks the double &&; threw me off a bit...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says, you must replace `...` by `&#8230;` :

```
<string name="txt_urbeautiful">What&#8230;</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"&#xb7;"
```

That will represent .(dot ) in xml ,

XML does not use \ue*** notation. Character references, starting with &#, may be used, but they are mostly not needed. XML is usually used with UTF-8 character encoding, so that each character can be written as such.